# SQL for Large Data?-Android

Tags: java, android, sql, database

I need a large database to be stored, I have thought of using SQL to do so.I am aware of some cons of it, I do not want my data to be cleared by a user. I do not want to complete my project and regret using SQL later, if there are any suggestions in that case I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Used SharedPref.

Comment: Define "large".

Comment: @Andreas 1GB  or less,I am trying to reduce it, but it's1 GB for now

Comment: @Rab,are you sure?,as it's a large file for now

Comment: What are you trying to add what is 1GB?

Comment: @Rab,they are text files,Essential, as they hold great value in the app

Comment: Well, you can try this https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: try [snappydb](http://www.snappydb.com/) if you dont care about sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store "large" amounts of data on the Android device, see the [Training for Android: Saving Data](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) guide:

> Most Android apps need to save data, even if only to save information about the app state during `onPause()` so the user's progress is not lost. Most non-trivial apps also need to save user settings, and **some apps must manage large amounts of information in files and databases**. This class introduces you to the principal data storage options in Android, including:
>
> - Saving key-value pairs of simple data types in a shared preferences file
> - Saving arbitrary files in Android's file system
> - Using databases managed by SQLite

Answer (score -2):

I think you are confusing some database terminology

SQL stands for Structured Query Language, It is a language only used to interact with a database. Just like in a conversation a language is used as a medium to convey information, but it does not matter how much information is transferred, you could speak in German or French and it would be the same. Similarly choosing whether to use SQL is completely independent of how much data you store in your database.

What I think you are trying to find the the most optimal database management system. The most popular of which are MySQL, Oracle Database, Microsoft SQL and IBM DB2. (a list of which can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system#Market_share)).

I'd recommend you use MySQL as it is relatively easy and can handle good amounts of data (more than enough for an android app). Have a look at their [website](https://www.mysql.com/) and see whether you like it

Comment: I believe OP is talking about storing data *on* the Android device, not on a server.

Comment: @Jort de Bokx ,Thank you,I'll Surely consider using MySQL

Comment: I'm pretty sure MySQL is for servers.

Comment: @Andreas,I do not want it to be saved online

Comment: Will MySQL make the info need internet for the data to be accessible? @Andreas

Comment: @Rab will MySQL make internet essential for accessing data?

Comment: @Anonymous If you want to store data on the Android device, not in an online database on a server somewhere, you should use the SQLite that comes with Android. See [Training for Android: Saving Data in SQL Databases](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html). You should go through the full [Saving Data](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) section, *then* decide on how you want to store data.

Comment: @Andreas by "store data in the Android device" does it mean its going to be saved in the Internal storage of the device accessible to the user?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, it means data is available any time, even when in Airplane mode, or traveling through the mountains. Just make sure you don't exceed storage capacity of the device (and leave some for other apps too).

Comment: @Andreas thank you for your help,got a clear view on the project, waiting to use the app travelling through the mountains :)

Comment: MySQL is server based

Comment: It is for external purposes.